# Better using angularjs instead of jquery in this case?

Tags: jquery, angular, symfony

I have heard about angularJs but **I don't know it yet** and I'm working in new project **Symfony3** and I had used to use jquery in the others projects.

I use jquery and ajax to submit forms , remove entries, live search form , showing form errors ....

So I do not want to realize a complete application with Angularjs, and as I do not know this framework yet, I would like to know if angularjs can do all those things above better than jquery and minus code or not, if so I start to learn it then.

what do you advise me ?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackOverflow. Please use other channels to ask this kind of question (primarily opinion based)

Comment: I advise you to implement using both separately and try out atleast key pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting to use Angular, you should start using Angular2 with Typescript. That is the best way to go and the investment of learning it will be worth it. It is not worth to start learning Angular 1 now. Another thing to be sure is that Angular (1 or 2) can do most of the stuff that jQuery can (especially Angular2). You should not be skeptic about the power of Angular.. It will not disappoint you and you can go full client-side which will make your app fly and everyone will be satisfied :)

Good Luck, the best place to start is angular.io

Comment: " can do EVERYTHING that jQuery can but way better (especially Angular2). " Quite a bold statement :D

Comment: When I think that everything is very abstracted, you dont manipulate the DOM directly, you can easily move your logic into a worker and forget about IDs on elements and things. Than with AoT you get generated code which is at lowest possible level for the js runtime, and its not using reflection so the engine can optimize itself by faster accessing the tree, im pretty sure its better than jQuery :D

Comment: I don't say jQuery is better, just saying that "Angular2 can do EVERYTHING that jQuery can" isn't quite right. There are kinds of web applications where jQuery is probably a much better fit than Angular2 and for different kinds of web applications Angular2 is a better fit, but saying one is much better than the other without considering the exact requirments is usually just plain wrong.

Comment: Not to mention that the jQuery api has numerous features in it that are not built into angular directly. That doesn't mean you can't easily work around them but it does require writing specific code to do it if you intend to use those features

Comment: Okay, I changed the "EVERYTHING" part. You are right, I am too much of Angular fanboy i guess